# How can I use $broadcast/$on in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass a string from one controller to another using $broadcast/$on, however it is not working. My `data` is coming as `undefined`

First Controller

```
var search = $scope.searchString; 
$rootScope.$broadcast('searchString', search);
```

Second Controller

```
 $scope.$on('searchString', function(events, data){
                console.log("data", data);
            });
```

From the first controller, I can see the `search` value is being passed

Comment: Are both controllers in the same level? Which one is the parent which one is the child? Also are they completely unrelated?

Answer (score 0):

if you broadcast through `$rootscope` you should receive on `$rootscope`

First Controller

```
var search = $rootScope.searchString; 
$rootScope.$broadcast('searchString', search);
```

Second Controller

```
$rootScope.$on('searchString', function(events, data){
    console.log("data", data);
});
```

Comment: this gave me an error ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$on')```. I have defined $rootScope

Comment: @newbie sorry udpated my answer